# TDBGrid não que atualizar os dados em delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Bom dia, estou fazendo um sistema para uma biblioteca e no grid de pesquisa de livros que ao digitar o id do livro no txtbox ele atualiza e mostra na grid os resultados, mas o grid não esta atualizando e os dados continuam na grid e não mudam.
Se alguem souber o que é agradeço desde ja.

```
    procedure Tfrm_alocar.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var parametro:integer;
    begin

      parametro := strtoint(txt_livro.Text);

      Form_dados.Modulo_Dados.Query_livros.Close;
      Form_dados.Modulo_Dados.Query_livros.sql.Clear;
      Form_dados.Modulo_Dados.Query_livros.sql.Add('select * from livros where id = :parametro');
     Form_dados.Modulo_Dados.Query_livros.Parameters.ParamByName('parametro').Value := parametro;
      Form_dados.Modulo_Dados.Query_livros.Open;

      GridLivros.Update;
      GridLivros.Refresh;

    end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenho um palpite do que pode estar acontecendo. Você está atualizando o componente query_livros. Talvez o grid esteja ligado a um ClientDataset e não ao query_livros. É comum fazermos a ligação database -> query -> datasetprovider -> clientdataset -> datasource -> dbgrid. Se for o caso, você deve fazer close no ClientDataset e não na query_livros. Mais ou menos isso:

```
cds.Close;
qry.ParamByName('parametro').AsInteger := parametro;
cds.Open;
```

Comment: blz vou tentar aqui mais e mais ou menos isso msm tem a conexao ao banco do sql server - query dos livros - dataset

Comment: bom o problema é que esse datasource n tem o close vou tentar migrar pro data set